# Как я могу привязать контроллер из control rig к компоненту в bluprint классе?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4

Я пытаюсь разобраться как работает Control Rig в UE4 и у меня возник вопрос. Как я могу привязать контроллер к какому либо компоненту, например в Blueprin-те моего персонажа?

И так мы имеем Pawn Blueprint с персонажем и Control Rig.
Я настроил контроллер с помощью которого можно управлять правой рукой.

[image: контроллер управляющий рукой]

Отлично всё работает, но теперь нужно как-то привязать этот контроллер например к Scene компоненту в Blueprin-те персонажа.

Я попробовал создать новый параметр и передать в него трансформацию Scene компонента, который называется TestJoint.

[image: Новый параметр]

[image: передача трансформации]

Но как вы видите это не работает и рука ведёт себя очень странно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этом и заключается вся проблема. Буду благодарен за помощь, а также если вы оставите какие-то ссылки которые могут помочь мне разобраться.